# How can I remove "inverse" that was added by fluent-nhibernate convention?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have the following HasMany convention:

```
instance.Key.Column( instance.EntityType.Name + "Fk" );
instance.Inverse();
instance.Cascade.All();
```

That I am then trying to override to remove the Inverse part of it

```
mapping.HasMany(x => x.Details).Cascade.All().KeyColumn(mapping.EntityType.Name + "Fk")
```

Unfortunately this isn't removing the inverse and if I generate the hbmxml files using the  ExportTo function it still shows **inverse="true"**.

I have tested that my override is being picked up by changing the KeyColumn name and this change does show in the hbmxml files.

How can I remove the **Inverse()** in the override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `.Not.Inverse()` not work?

Comment: Yes! Thank you, easy when you know how!